# Is there a way to allow administrator users to enter a credit card payment?

Tags: commerce

If we:

- Go to **COMMERCE->ORDERS->CREATE_NEW_ORDER**
- Create a new order by filling in customer and product information
- Save the order
- Then go to the **PAYMENTS** tab and click **ADD PAYMENT**

All we get is the message "There are no reusable payment methods available for the selected gateway."

We are using Authorize.net but we get the same message with the Test Gateway (on-site).

I'm not sure why we're getting this message. Is there a way to allow admins to enter a customer's credit card info to an order via the backend?

Comment: `I'm not sure why we're getting this message` that check is done [here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/payment/src/Form/PaymentAddForm.php#L178)

Comment: Thank you for the link but this doesn't help me much. I'm still not sure why admins can't enter a new credit card for a backend order. Is there any way around this?